# Searching in Yii with Multiple MANY_MANY Conditions

Tags: php, search, many-to-many, yii

In the Yii framework, I'm trying to figure out how to query and get back results that match multiple tags in the following system:

```
posts
id

tags
id

post_tags
post_id
tag_id
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return a result of posts which match tag 1 AND tag 2. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

---

### EDIT

So far I seem to have it working like this:

In `Post` relations:

```
array(
    'tags'  => array( self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', Yii::app()->db->tablePrefix . 'post_tag(post_id,tag_id)' ),
);
```

In `PostTag` relations

```
array( 
    'post'  => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Post', 'post_id' ),
    'tag'   => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tag', 'tag_id' ),
);
```

In my `Controller`

```
$tags   = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // Match N tags

$criteria           = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = 'post';
$criteria->addInCondition( 'tag_id', $tags );
$criteria->group    = 'post_id';
$criteria->having   = 'COUNT(*) = ' . count( $tags );

$matchedPostTags    = PostTag::model()->findAll( $criteria );
foreach( $matchedPostTags as $matchedPostTag )
{
    $post   = $matchedPostTag->post;
    // Do what you want with it.
}
```

Now if anyone can figure out how to get this working with CActiveDataProvider I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anybody curious, this is how I got it to work:

`Post` relations

```
array(
    'tags'      => array( self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', Yii::app()->db->tablePrefix . 'post_tag(post_id,tag_id)' ),
    'post_tags' => array( self::HAS_MANY, 'PostTag', 'post_id' ),
);
```

`PostTag` relations

```
array( 
    'post'  => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Post', 'post_id' ),
    'tag'   => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tag', 'tag_id' ),
);
```

`Controller`

```
$tags   = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // Match N tags

$criteria           = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array( 
    'post_tags' => array(
        'condition' => 'tag_id IN ('.implode($tags).')',
        'group'     => 'post_id',
        'having'    => 'COUNT(*) = ' . count( $tags ),
    )
);
$criteria->together = true;

$dataProvider   = new CActiveDataProvider( 'Post', array(
    'criteria'  => $criteria,
) );
```

This is now working with my ListView to show only posts that match ALL specified tags.

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer so others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

You should add the relationship between `Post` and `PostTag` in your `Post` class. Put it on `relations()`

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'post_tags'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PostTag', 'post_id'),
    );
}
```

After that on your controller class add this code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('post_tags.tag_id', array(1, 2));
$criteria->with('post_tags');

$models = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Thank you. This produced what I have been able to produce on my own so far: "WHERE post_tags.tag_id IN (1,2)" which is producing posts which match 1 OR 2. The problem I was having was trying to make the results match only posts with 1 AND 2.

Comment: you said that "I'm trying to figure out how to return a result of posts which match tag 1 AND tag 2." Tag ID or Post ID? the above solution will display all posts which tag id is in 1 or 2

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it displays all posts which tag id is in 1 or 2. What I'm looking for is how to display only posts which are tagged with 1 AND 2.